# I have a Panasonic CD Player Model SL-PJ24A, and am wondering what Power cable I would need

Tags: power-supply

Panasonic CD Player Model SL-PJ24A

Power sticker states '50/60Hz 240V 13W'

Above power input says 'AC  IN'

Comment: What is the domestic AC power voltage in your country?

Comment: A picture of the inlet plug on the back of the player would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture in the manual, it looks very much like a C7 "figure of 8" connector.  If so, these are very commonly used on small appliances.